# nhibernate webApp serializing fluently configurated object

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, nhibernate, serialization, fluent-nhibernate

Since I am begginer with nhibernate I'm going to risk to ask a repeated question.

Can someone show me on practical example serialization fluently created configuration object with one mapped entity to be simple as it can. I do not ask for mapping of entity itself, neither actual example of an entity, just  nhib.configuration and serialization on disk having web app. usage in mind.

Please ask if you need more information.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sample code](https://github.com/ayende/Effectus/blob/master/Effectus/Infrastructure/BootStrapper.cs) which demonstrates how to serialize/deserialize.

essentially it is

```
using(var file = File.Open(SerializedConfiguration, FileMode.Create))
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(file, configuration);
}
```

Note: all own implementations of interfaces like IUserType, IConnectionProvider, ... have to be serializable.

Comment: thanks, but actually where this file will be saved? I dont see any save location.

Comment: SerializedConfiguration is the path to the file which should be generated. in the example it is a constant filename without path which means it will be saved in the app dir. you have to provide some meaningful path yourself